# sending email to distribution list using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, html-email

I'm trying to send emails to people in a distribution list in my company using python. My company uses outlook.

When I send to individual users specifying their email, it works perfectly. However I need to use the distribution list, since the recipients are updated by my IT department and I cant keep updating the email list whenever it changes.

Whomever has used outlook, you might recall that the distribution list starts with an exclamation mark like so: `!groupdept@company.com`

I am using the following method to send emails using python:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from smtplib import SMTP
import smtplib
import sys

subject = "Group Email"
fromm = 'me@company.com'
recipients = ['someone@company.com, someonelse@company.com'] 
emaillist = [elem.strip().split(',') for elem in recipients]

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = subject
msg['From'] = fromm

html = """\
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="font-size:18px;">
{0}
</body>
</html>
""".format(df2.style
       .set_properties(**{'border': '2.5pt solid green', 'color': 'magenta', 'font-size': '15pt'})
       .hide_index()
       .hide_columns()
       .render()
      )
message = MIMEText(html, 'html')
msg.attach(message)
server = smtplib.SMTP('00.0.0.00', 25)
server.sendmail(msg['From'], emaillist , msg.as_string())
```

The above method works well for comma separated recipients. However if I use `!groupdept@company.com` it doesn't work, which I can understand since that is an MS Outlook functionality.

Has anyone achieved this before?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67538461/1003798

I think you need to talk your NOC guys.

Comment: @bombayquant I did previously see that post while i was researching this topic. However in my case it is a little different since there is a specific identifier Outlook uses to identify mailing list. Its not just a normal email address.

Comment: I don't know. In my experience, distribution lists are the same as individual email addresses. Try without the exclamation mark as an experiment.

Comment: @ddastrodd Thank You. That worked.
Ocam's razor I guess :)